# How to get all the blocks when forking the chain?

Tags: substrate-node

I am using [subalfred](https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/state.html#command-state-fork-off) to fork my chain and was able to achieve  it, I got the latest state of the `old-chain` to the `forked-chain` but the `forked-chain` is starting from the genesis block or we can say starting a new chain with the state of the `old-chain`.

But what I want is to get all the blocks from `old-chain` to `forked-chain` like what `Ethereum` did in their **London Hard Fork**.

Is there a way to that in substrate means retaining all the blocks even after doing a `hard-fork`, if yes please point to the resources for the same.