# Is it possible to bootstrap a parachain node from pre-existing solo chainstate?

Tags: parachain, storage, migration, database, storage-migration

Let's imagine a scenario where a team is running a substrate private network and have all their chainstate that they want to move to a parachain after acquiring a slot. My question is, when the team moves all their runtime logic into a cumulus template and starts the process for becoming a parachain, is it possible to bring this solo chainstate from the old chain to the parachain? In other words, is it possible to start a parachain with block N >> 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Have a look at this previous question: [how we can migrate the solochain data to the parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7658/how-we-can-migrate-the-solochain-data-to-the-parachain)

Also, have a look at this video: [Sub0 Online: Storage Migration - Standalone chain to Parachain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sIgvyRFs-N4)

Answer (score 1):

I have also asked a similar question [How to get all the blocks when forking the chain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/how-to-get-all-the-blocks-when-forking-the-chain), where `block N >> 0` still waiting for an answer. In the meantime I can share my findings, there are different ways to persist the current state of the chain while converting solochain to a parachain but all of them start from `block 0`, one way is already mentioned by Rodrigo that is storage migration and other are as follows:

- You can use [fork-off-substrate](https://github.com/maxsam4/fork-off-substrate) to persist the current state of your chain but I am not sure if it can convert solochain to parachain.
- Other is [subalfred](https://subalfred.hack.ink/user/cli/state.html#command-state-fork-off), this I have tried and was able to convert solochian to relay-chain and vice versa with its old state being persist and I hope it will work for solochain to parachain also but it will start from `block 0`. To convert the chain you need to use `override` command of subalfred.

Comment: I will look into subalfred and fork-off. I don't think the relay chain will accept a parachain starting from block N >> 0 anyways, but it's still interesting to start from a different state. With the other approach i.e. starting with a genesis state, I am still trying to figure out how exactly to filter the keys in storage as we must remember that a solochain comes with pallets like aura/babe/grandpa which are not needed in a parachain so these keys must be eliminated. That's my theoretical understanding so far.

Comment: @Purple_Turtle if you are starting from `block 0` than there is no need to care about keys as you can override it with `subalfred` and need to insert them again.